# Metadata stripped?

Tags: 7, media

Why does it seem that when I upload images through Drupal the metadata disappears? How can I preserve it? I am having trouble finding an layperson's answer here.

Comment: You are talking about the EXIF and ITPC metadata, correct?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably using image styles. These images are created based on your original upload. So they are new images.

Comment: GD doesn't support extracting/copying EXIF, so this makes sense